# Bootstrap displays right on resize but not on smartphone

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

For some reason my bootstrap website (here the [link](http://cms.hk-holz.de/index.php/products/index/2)) displays right if I resize the window but it doesn't display correct on my smartphone. With 'right' I mean that the navbar-toggles are enabled. Please use "show source" to check where the error could be.

Comment: Post the code here, not just a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this meta tag?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

[more ...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Answer (score 1):

Use this in the head to take the size of the smartphone and resize

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">`

sorry its my first post.

Comment: well he has that on his website. please check before you post stuff .

Comment: He does not have that, he has `<meta author="HK-HOLZ GmbH" viewport="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />` which is not correct

Answer (score 0):

Okay you have to post your code so we edit it. but I went to your website and took a look at the source code. Right after the body you want to put your container class.

```
<body>
   <div class="container">
       ...........
    </div>
</body>
```

In that class container you want to add a div of class row. replace the div that has navbar class by nav

```
<div class="row ">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle search-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                </button>
                 //..... navbar remaining code
        </div>//remove the div container it might be one of your multiple problems
   </nav>
</div>
<div class="row ">
     ... rest of your website code. 
</div>
```

Comment: took a look that's why i sent this reply. thanks for tip